# Where is the schema for XSL-FO?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

Does anyone know how/where to download XSL-FO 1.1 schema? I not able to find an XSL-FO 1.1 schema, so many person saying not available. Please let me know if you know where to find the schema or suggest to me how to determine validation errors.

Note: the Oxygen guy replied to me "There still is no proper schema available for XSL-FO 1.1."

Comment: I don't think there's such a thing, delivered "officially" by w3c, however if you read xsl-fo specification, content models are described. Please also have a look to http://apache-fop.1065347.n5.nabble.com/XSL-FO-Schema-or-DTD-td10919.html - you might find unofficial distributed of a DTD.

Answer (score 10):

There is no official XML schema for XSL-FO, but one of the following might be of use to you:

- [FOP](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) has an [XSD for XSL-FO](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xmlgraphics/fop/trunk/fop/src/foschema/fop.xsd).
- [RenderX](http://www.renderx.com/index.html) has a [DTD for XSL-FO](http://www.renderx.com/tools/validators.html).

Comment: The FOP version works really well except one thing—for languages it uses codes in upper case (like in ancient times of coding), which is not so much common practice today. FOP ignores them. It is sufficient to change codes and the file is nearly perfect (imho).

Answer (score 5):

**focheck** (https://github.com/AntennaHouse/focheck) is a Relax NG schema and Schematron for XSL-FO 1.1 as well as Antenna House extensions.  Releases also include a W3C XSD generated from the Relax NG plus an Oxygen add-on framework that you can download within Oxygen so you can easily validate your XSL-FO while editing.

**focheck** parses property value expressions using an XSLT-based parser generated by the REx parser generator plus an XSLT library for reducing the parse tree to XSL-FO datatypes.

Comment: Thank you for creating and making this available.