# Intellij plugin for XSL-FO?

Tags: intellij-idea, xsl-fo

I am creating a few Apache FOP documents using velocity and XSLT templates and I find it very difficult to work with Intellij IDE because it doesn't give me hints of the allowed attributes for a node and marks as "error" all the nodes. Is there any plug-in I can use that solves this problem?

I have tried with the only one I have found online:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7736?pr=idea

But it doesn't seem to do much.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: If you show a complete XSL-FO document (as text, not in an image), someone could also point out the errors in it for now. Help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I am not interested in the errors in the code. The code I can fix. I am interested in showing what I see in intelliJ hoping someone will help me with that.

Comment: Then why do you show a screenshot of XSL-FO code?

Comment: To show that all the stuff from xsl-fo is in red in intellij. As I said, what I want is to show that so that somebody can have an idea of what I see and tell me if there is a way to fix it.

Comment: There are wonderful context sensitive editors for writing pure XSL FO like oXygen and Altova XMLSpy

Comment: I would also recommend oXygen XML Editor. It provides a much richer IDE for XSLT and XSL-FO development workflow, including a proper XSLT debugger.

Answer (score 5):

It seems, that you don't have properly set XML schema for namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format` in the IDE. I had the
same problem when I asked Idea to download missing schemas.
Instead of downloading, the IntelliJ Idea created the empty one.

This helped me:

1. Download XML schema for XSL:FO files (from Apache/FOP or RenderX).
2. In the IntelliJ Idea associate URI `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format` to the downloaded file (Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Schemas & DTDs).

Links:

1. [XML Schemas for XSL:FO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31230119/1685927)
2. [IntelliJ Idea Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/referencing-xml-schemas-and-dtds.html)

Comment: Or download the XSD version of the schema from https://github.com/AntennaHouse/focheck

Comment: Nice idea, but neither of those options solve the xsl:use-attribute-sets problem within fo: namespace tags.